# `float` package not playing nice with `sidecap` package?

Tags: floats, captions, sidecap

In trying to answer [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125106/22413), I thought it would be easy to add a new float environment using the `float` package.  However, the labeling of the caption is not getting correctly formatted.

Because I'm creating a new float that I want labeled with a side caption, I dug into the `sidecap` package and created a new environment to match the new float.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}     

%% setting up new float
\usepackage{float}
\floatname{mySpecialFloat}{Special Float}
\newfloat{mySpecialFloat}{tbhp}{lst}[chapter]
\newcommand{\listofSpecialFloats}{\listof{mySpecialFloat}{List of Special Floats}}

%% setting up side captions
\usepackage[wide]{sidecap}                                      
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\SC@specialFloat@vpos{\def\SC@specialFloat@vpos{b}}
\newenvironment{SCspecialFloat}{\SC@float[\SC@specialFloat@vpos]{mySpecialFloat}}{\endSC@float}
\newenvironment{SCspecialFloat*}{\SC@dblfloat[\SC@specialFloat@vpos]{mySpecialFloat}}{\endSC@dblfloat}
\makeatother

%% setting up formatting for cpations
\usepackage
  [
    font=footnotesize,
    format=plain,
    labelfont={bf,sf},
    textfont={it},
    width=10pt
  ]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\listofSpecialFloats

\begin{mySpecialFloat}
  \centering
    Hello
  \caption[toc entry for hello]{Hello}
\end{mySpecialFloat}

\begin{SCspecialFloat}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}
  \caption[toc entry for lipsum]{My caption content}
  \label{fig:src:01}
\end{SCspecialFloat}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

What I find interesting is that everything seems to be working correctly.  The listing command knows about all my special floats.  The only thing that doesn't seem to be working correctly is the label for the caption for the side caption float.

I know this could be accomplished with `newfloat`, but I'm wondering what's happening here.  Why is the label name getting lost in the `sidecap` environment?

**UPDATE**

There seems to be a conflict in naming conventions used by `float` and those expected by `sidecap`.

It seems this can be fixed if I add the following line to my code for setting up the captions:

```
\@namedef{mySpecialFloatname}{Special Float}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `caption` package bundle resp. the `newfloat` package already offers this functionality since it defines an SC-variant automatically if the `sidecap` package is loaded:

```
\documentclass{book}     

%% setting up side captions
\usepackage[wide]{sidecap}                                      

%% setting up new float
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment
  [name={Special Float},listname={List of Special Floats},fileext=lst,placement=tbhp]
  {SpecialFloat}

%% setting up formatting for cpations
\usepackage
  [
    font=footnotesize,
    format=plain,
    labelfont={bf,sf},
    textfont={it},
    width=10pt
  ]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\listofSpecialFloats

\begin{SpecialFloat}
  \centering
    Hello
  \caption[toc entry for hello]{Hello}
\end{SpecialFloat}

\begin{SCSpecialFloat}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}
  \caption[toc entry for lipsum]{My caption content}
  \label{fig:src:01}
\end{SCSpecialFloat}

\end{document}
```