# Two-column figure with side caption using revtex

Tags: floats, captions, two-column, revtex

How can one create a two-column figure with a side caption using revtex?

I've seen this in published articles but did not find any information how to achieve it.

Comment: Welcome, Felix or Christian! Please post a small complete document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that shows your setup and that we can use as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using `revtex4-1`. This is the code that I am using for when I want a figure on both columns. You might need to modify the `scale` parameter for your images.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\begin{document}
\onecolumngrid

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{filename1.png}
    \caption{subcaption1}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}% 
~ 
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{filename2.png}
    \caption{subcaption2}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{fig:caption}
\end{figure}

\twocolumngrid
\end{document}
```

You might be tempted to use `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` instead of `caption` and `subcaption` but then you will not be able to have, ***as far as I know***, the main capture for your figure. I am sure there is a way around it I just couldn't find it.

[image: revtex4-1 centered figure in reprint mode]

The code when `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` is used would look something like this:

```
\onecolumngrid
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[subcaption1]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1.png}}
~
\subfloat[subcaption2]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig2.png}}
\end{figure}
\twocolumngrid
```

### EDIT

**The caption can be moved to the side by using** `sidecap`. Therefore, the code is modified by changing the `figure` to `SCfigure` and removing the `[h]` from the `SCfigure`. To achieve optimal side captions, the user has to adjust manually the figure boarders or use `minipage` to separate the figure and the caption.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\begin{document}
\onecolumngrid

\begin{SCfigure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{filename1.png}
    \caption{subcaption1}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}% 
~ 
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{filename2.png}
    \caption{subcaption2}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{some caption that is used as a means to test the side caption of this figure}\label{fig:caption}
\end{SCfigure}

\twocolumngrid
\end{document}
```

[image: revtex4-1-fix2]

Comment: But caption should be on side of images, if I correctly understand (very unclear) question and images occupy width of two columns ... It would be sensible to wait that OP clarify his question.

Comment: I forgot about that part when I posted to be honest. I don't fully understand why someone would want that since it is a very uncommon caption setup for a paper. Anyway, I am working on a solution now based on [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125106/listings-and-sidecap-side-captions-for-listings)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.\usepackage{sidecap}
\begin{SCfigure*}
    \includegraphics{...}
  \caption{...}
\end{SCfigure*} seems to do the right thing.